# Divs according to mysql result in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

First off, sorry if the title is confusing! I'm working on a part of a blog that determines how lists of recent posts (sometimes determined by a date) in a category are to be displayed. In the database, each category has a "type" set that determines whether the div it goes in is small or large.

I can get the results to display but each link in the list has its own div, instead of being contained in one "main" category div.

**Shorter explanation:**
The database pulls results from the categories table and the posts table, as you can see in the query. The loop then runs so that the category boxes and the links in them can be created dynamically. 
The problem is that the divs, which are supposed to house a list of links, are instead wrapping around each individual link and not the set that is desired.

While the code below shows only two "types", I had planned on adding more in the future.

Here is the code

```
                <?
            require("classes/Database.class.php"); 

            $db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE); 
            $time = $_REQUEST['time'];

            $db->connect(); 

            $sql = "SELECT 
                cm.id,
                cm.title AS cmtitle,
                cm.sectionid,
                cm.type AS cmtype,
                cd.id,
                cd.time,
                cd.link,
                cd.title,
                cd.description,
                cd.sectionid AS sectionid
                FROM c_main AS cm
                JOIN c_data AS cd ON cd.sectionid=cm.sectionid
                WHERE cd.sectionid=cm.sectionid AND time = '".$time."' ORDER by id ASC";

            $rows = $db->query($sql); 


            while($record = $db->fetch_array($rows)){

                          //determine what div to use by checking "type"
            if ($record['cmtype'] == 'large') {
            ?>
            <div class="large" >
            <?
            } elseif ($record['cmtype'] == 'small') { 
            ?>
            <div class="small">
            <?

            } 

            for($x =0; $x <= $db->affected_rows; ++$x)
            {
            if ($record['cmtype'] == 'small') {
            echo $record['title'].'<br/>';
            } else {
            echo $record['title'].'<br/>'.$record['description'];

            }
            break;
            }
            echo '</div>';

            }
            $db->close(); 
            ?>
```

Basically I am trying to have it like this:

```
    /-------------------\
   |    Category Title  |
   |  -relevant link    |
   |  -relevant link    |
   \____________________/ 
    /-------------------\
   |    Category Title  |
   |  -relevant link    |
   |  -relevant link    |
   \____________________/ 
 .... and so on for each subsequent category
```

And not this (which is how it's being outputted)

```
/-------------\
\relevant link/
 -------------
/-------------\
\relevant link/
 -------------
 etc.
```

Here is the mysql wrapper I'm currently using, if that's of any significance http://ricocheting.com/scripts/php_mysql_wrapper.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code will echo a div for every row, that is your problem/question.

my suggestion is to create two queries: one selecting all links of type A and the second query selecting all links of type B (`WHERE type = '…'`)

then you'll have to print the starting tag of your first div:

```
echo '<div class="large">';
```

after that, loop your result and output your links:

```
while(($record = $db->fetch_assoc($rows)) !== FALSE){
  echo htmlspecialchars($record['title']),'<br/>';
}
```

close your div:

```
echo '</div>';
```

now you can start your second category, same game, same rules:

- open div
- loop results
- close div

~~~

another way like others said to order your result by type, then by id (`ORDER BY type, id`) and then check for a change in the row’s type:

```
$currenttype = '';
while(($record = $db->fetch_assoc($rows)) !== FALSE) {
  $currenttype = $record['cmtype'];
  echo '<div class="',htmlspecialchars($record['cmtype']),'">';

  while($record['cmtype'] == $currenttype
  && ($record = $db->fetch_assoc($rows)) !== FALSE) {
    // output link according to your type:
    echo htmlspecialchars($record['title']);
  }

  echo '</div>';
}
```

i assume this is what you wanted to achieve in the first place

Comment: With the first suggestion, what if I add more types of divs? Ideally that is what I will do.

With the second, the divs still appear to be coming out quite weird. They appear to be all merged in one div.

Comment: with the first suggestion you’d have to create a new query for each type of div. for the latter … i forgot to close the div, editing my answer accordingly

Comment: The div is now only appearing with the first result for each type.

Comment: added another loop, maybe it’s still not perfect, but it’s a good groundwork, i’m sure you can work out the rest by yourself with a little thinking.

Comment: thanks, with a little modification that really did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want 2 divs, one large and one small, you should do `ORDER BY cmtype`, and then you will only need to create a div when the type changes or it is the first type.

Comment: I intend to add more types of divs, so would this still be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I get this completely wrong, but if you want to display the elements grouped by their type I think you should order them by type straight away, so that order of elements is correct when you start outputting HTML code?

Comment: I'm a bit of a php newbie, so I hope you don't mind me asking for a bit of clarification.

Comment: Basically I was referring to the same like Clash. If you want to have one div per category, you should have the result sorted by SQL. Then iterate through the results, creating a new div only when cmtype changes. This will work fine, even if you add new categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain about your table contents you can use:

```
echo "<div class='" . $record['cmtype'] . "'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i am wrong in understanding your question, but you try to add all **relevant link** in a single DIV, then check your php result html (browser->view source)